# How to turn off or dim the camera if the camera is used by any app?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I want to make an application that controls the camera. If the camera is used when this app is opened, the camera should be turned off or dimmed.  Is this possible?

```
    //this method is checking the camera
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
                    super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
                    super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
                    //how do I turn off the camera ?
                }
            }, new Handler());
        }
```

Comment: You can use device admin to disable and enable camera at will, is that helpful? Here for more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin

Comment: @DanBaruch 
Device admin deprecation. Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), some admin policies will be marked as deprecated when invoked by a device admin. We recommend you start to prepare now for this change. To learn more and see the migration options, read Device admin deprecation.

Comment: @DanBaruch do you have any other suggestions

Comment: Device admin is not deprecated. What they are talking about is not relevant to your camera needs.

Comment: @DanBaruch `DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName deviceAdminSample = ?????  what will i write here

        dpm.setCameraDisabled(deviceAdminSample, true); `

Answer (score 0):

You create a class to accept the DeviceAdmin rights:

```
public  class MyDevicePolicyReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "LOG";

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
}

@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return disableRequestedSeq;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
}
```

You register it as follows:

```
    public ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
    public DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

    mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
                MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        if(mDPM == null || !mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,mDeviceAdminSample);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                "Your_String");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ANY_REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
```

Comment: Can you check the code I shared? where did I go wrong.

Comment: The code you shared does not include the code I gave you. After you have run the code I gave you here, you can disable the camera with the following line:             **mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, false);**

Comment: I added mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, false); 
but I am getting this error
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin `ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MyDevicePolicyReceiver}
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)`

Comment: and I added
`<receiver
            android:name=".MyDevicePolicyReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: ` java.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MyDevicePolicyReceiver} is not a device owner or profile owner, so may not use policy: disable-camera`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkCam(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
                Log.e("onCameraAvailable","-");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
                super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);

                Log.e("onCameraUnavailable","-");

                mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
                        MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
                mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
                if(mDPM == null || !mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                            "Your_String");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 132);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, new Handler());
    }
}
```